# Error when building project in business central

Tags: jbpm

I created new project with simple business process in jBPM Business Central app. 
Business Central in my case hosted on WildFly 17 on java 12 in domain mode. When I'm trying to build new kjar project (does not matter which project) this error occurs:

```
2019-07-24 16:52:53,330 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44) java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: Cannot define nest member class java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject$Cache + within different package then class net.bytebuddy.mirror.AccessibleObject
2019-07-24 16:52:53,331 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection$Dispatcher$Initializable$Unavailable.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:410)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,331 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingReflection.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:235)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,331 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$AbstractBase.inject(ClassInjector.java:111)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,331 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$InjectionDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:232)
...
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:906)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:51)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor.apply(LocalSourceConfigExecutor.java:33)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//org.kie.workbench.common.services.backend.builder.ala.LocalSourceConfigExecutor$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.apply(Unknown Source)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.execution.PipelineExecutor.lambda$continuePipeline$0(PipelineExecutor.java:114)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,337 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at deployment.business-central.war//org.guvnor.ala.pipeline.StageUtil$1.execute(StageUtil.java:38)
...
2019-07-24 16:52:53,342 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44) Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${input.root-path}
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2936)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3107)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3189)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3148)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:623)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    at java.base/java.net.URI.create(URI.java:904)
2019-07-24 16:52:53,343 ERROR [stderr] (default task-44)    ... 89 more
```

Stack trace is very long, stackoverflow not allow to post without reduction.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whats the version of jBPM you are using ? Also give a try with java 11, there might be compatibility issue as well.

Comment: I use 7.24. Yesterday I ask same question in google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/IJKcDNJ7b8k. And get the answer that developers not tested it on java 12. So, it is not a big problem, because I can run kie server on docker with proper java version, and call rest api from my app, which must run on java 12. For now, lets think that problem is not significant.